# az104 11 Implement monitoring -Log analytics workspace does not appear in Inventory pane

Tags: azure, azure-automation, azure-monitoring, azure-alerts, azure-log-analytics-workspace

Doing lab steps I found the below discrepencies to appear twice.

Supported Mappings as described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/how-to/region-mappings have given appropriate regions to deploy LogAnalytics workspace and Automation accounts.

On viewing the new AutomationAccount->Inventory pane under Configuration Management blade. I do not see the LogAnalytics workspace deployed earlier.

Comment: In which location you have created the Log Analytics Workspace ?

Comment: West US location

Comment: Could you please share the image of your Automation Account which shows Log Analytics Workspace Dropdown

Comment: It got resolved on its own but yes I was charged money on my card. Even though I have a free sub for a month. Credits went down, as it took more than a day for West US location to configure the Automation account and LogAnalytics space.